# Can't find the File Explorer part of the activity bar in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Suddenly I can't find the part of VS Code where I browse the files, the "Explorer", in the activity bar.

[image]

I've tried pressing `shift+cmd+e` to get it back (nothing happens), and looked in the context menu of the activity bar, but it's not there.

[image: context menu of vs code activity bar]

Opening the command pallet and running the command "collapse folders in explorer" results in the following error:
[image: error message]

Comment: Run the command: `View: Reset View Locations`.